# Why can't I override CORE::open with @_ instead of $_[0], $_[1], $_[2]?

Tags: perl, overriding

In trying to override the PERL CORE::open function, I tried this simple test case, which works:

```
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub {
  if (defined $_[2]) {
    CORE::open $_[0], $_[1], $_[2];
  } else {
    CORE::open $_[0], $_[1];
  }
}
```

Why doesn't using @_ work?:

```
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub {
    CORE::open @_;
  }
}
```

I get:

> Can't use string ("3") as a symbol ref while "strict refs"...

My purpose in overriding the function is to print a stack trace whenever open is called (not shown in the code snippet above).

Note that open was called with the three argument form, but I'd like to generalize the override method so that I am not testing for a specific number of parameters, i.e. so that I don't need to know how many parameters are expected.

```
my $fh;
open $fh, ">", "tmp.dummy" ;
```

Comment: Because of prototypes.  Also, if you want to override open, you'll need to specify the correct prototype in your new anonymous sub as well.

Comment: Also should test size of @_, not defined.  And handle more parameters. And don't forget 1-arg open :)

Answer (score 1):

Like most operators' operands, `open`'s operands are evaluated in scalar context.